# Android AlertDialog dismiss method does not work

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I've created an AlertDialog, but I can't close it...
I can see it and press the buttons, but when I press the "positive button", the program shall do some tasks and then close (dismiss) the dialog. All tasks are being done, without closing the dialog, it just flickers once (it might close and then reopen, I don't know).

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);
        builder.setTitle("Congratulations, you won!");
        builder.setMessage("Time: x seconds\nScore: xxxx\nHigh score: yyyy");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Play again!",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Doing stuff!
                        circle1Paint = yellowPaint;
                        circle2Paint = yellowPaint;
                        circle3Paint = yellowPaint;
                        playing = true;


                        // Trying to close it after doing "the stuff"
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Exit",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
        builder.create.show();
```

Thanks in advance!
CoderOgden

Comment: `dialog.dismiss();` => `finish();` and please avoid this: `System.exit(0);`

Comment: What do you mean? I just want to remove the dialog. System.exit(0) is put there to exit the program, what can I replace it with?

Comment: You should **NEVER** exit the program explicitly. It's a **REALLY BAD** design pattern! `finish();` closes your dialog.

Comment: How do I call finish() from a method in a view class?

Answer (score 0):

Into your exit button put dilog.dissmiss() and then finish();

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Exit",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dialog.dismiss(); 
                  finish();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Corrected mispelled `dismiss();`

Comment: The method finish() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} According to Java... And in the setPositiveButton I just want to shut the dialog!! How?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);
    builder.setTitle("Congratulations, you won!");
    builder.setMessage("Time: x seconds\nScore: xxxx\nHigh score: yyyy");

    builder.setNegativeButton("Exit",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
    AlertDialog myDialog = builder.create();
    builder.setPositiveButton("Play again!",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Doing stuff!
                    circle1Paint = yellowPaint;
                    circle2Paint = yellowPaint;
                    circle3Paint = yellowPaint;
                    playing = true;


                    // Trying to close it after doing "the stuff"
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    myDialog.show();
```